# on slideup can I clear out the input text field in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this little snippet in jQuery

```
    $('.cake_checkboxes').click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll('.quantity').first().slideToggle();
    });
```

here is my html

```
<input id="option-value-24" class="cake_checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="24" name="option[232][]" style="vertical-align: bottom;">
<label for="option-value-24"> Vanilla </label>
<div class="quantity" style="">
<span>
<input class="cake_quantities" type="text" name="quantity_24" size="3">
```

and I was wondering how to on slideUp how can i clear the value of the next cake_quantities input field...any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('.cake_checkboxes').click(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  $(this).nextAll('.quantity').first().slideToggle(function() {
  that.nextAll('.quantity').first().find('.cake_quantities').val("");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply place a callback function inside the slideToggle

```
    $('.cake_checkboxes').click(function(){
$(this).nextAll('.quantity').first().slideToggle(function() {
        $(".cake_quantities").val("");
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The .slideToggle() method takes a callback function that you can implement. In that function you have to check the current state of the entity and clear your input fields then.